# How to open a shell at the location of the path under the cursor when I'm in vim?

Tags: vim, command-line

I have a list of paths I want to go to.

I want to check what's going on there and then use rsync or other tools and these folders.

Any practical way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function! GotoPathUnderCursor()
   execute 'lcd ' . expand('<cfile>')
   shell
endfunction

command! GotoPathUnderCursor call GotoPathUnderCursor()
```

Now put cursor on a path in the file and execute

```
:GotoPathUnderCursor
```

The function changes current directory to the path under cursor (`<cfile>`) and executes a shell there. To make things even simpler define a mapping to call the function:

```
:nnoremap _some_key_ :call GotoPathUnderCursor()
```